# Seleniumlibrary command not working with Ride?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

The issue I'm having is with the command `Go Back` from the selenium library within RIDE.

I have tried to input the `Go Back` command into a test script im running. The website should then simulate a click on the back button within the browser (chrome). It however does not seem to work while it does tick off the step as done and passed. I googled some stuff and found out sometimes the browser isnt ready loading when trying to perform the next command and thus it could create an issue. Because of this i tried to implement the `Set Selenium Implicit Wait 10 seconds` command

In the img link below (can't post the img because im not 10 reputation) you can see that I have the command `Go Back` and `Set Selenium Implicit Wait 10 seconds`. Neither however seem to work (notice that while the timer is suppose to wiat 10 seconds. it is marked as completed in 00:00:00.003

https://gyazo.com/fa18566997436989ab5a6503b9064965

I noticed that both come from the seleniumlibrary and while installed and imported (or `Close Browser` would not work) neither works. I'm not sure what im doing wrong here. In the picture below is how i wrote it down in the testcase.

https://gyazo.com/7d914c7c74999177ae2dca4a02d4a4bb

Any help would be much appreciated into making the bowser use the back button and/or explaining why certain aspects of the seleniumlibrary don't seem to work.

Comment: I was not able to post the imgages. i dont have 10 reputation yet. And sorry in advanced for the spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

See the [implicit wait](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Implicit%20wait) section. It can be read like "the maximum time when waiting to find the element". When you use the `Go Back` keyword, there is no element to wait for, so it is immediate.

See here a complete example (that would work as long this question is on the first results page):

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Move Back On Browser
    Open Browser    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/robotframework%2bselenium?tab=Active    Chrome
    Scroll Element Into View    xpath=//a[.='Seleniumlibrary command not working with Ride?']/../..//div[contains(@class, 'excerpt')]    # Scroll to excerpt, because Cookie Policy ovelay is over URL element
    Capture Page Screenshot    active_questions.png
    Click Link    xpath=//a[.='Seleniumlibrary command not working with Ride?']
    Capture Page Screenshot    target_question.png
    Set Selenium Implicit Wait    10 seconds
    Go Back
    Capture Page Screenshot    after_go_back.png
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```